# Android facebook app on CDMA devices

Tags: android, facebook, gsm, cdma

I've an android `facebook` application.It works fine on *GSM* devices.But not on *CDMA* devices.

Will it run on both *GSM* & *CDMA* devices?

Comment: You only are saying it's not working and then asking whether it'll work.

Comment: My question is whether i need to add any permissions to run it on CDMA devices?

Answer (score 0):

Whether the phone is GSM or CDMA has nothing to do with the facebook application.

The facebook application will be able to get the data connection over either of them.

So, your facebook application ***should*** run on your CDMA phone.